# I have an Excel VBA file that fails to open. File and Excel crashes intermittantly. I get the following error message. Does anyone know what this is?

Tags: excel, vba

error095560_01.xmlErrors were detected in file 'https://firstporter.sharepoint.com/sites/PSPC-RPSB/Shared Documents/23-04, Carling Campus Geothermal/01 Financial/01 dome/dome Option 3 Hybrid Geo 2024.01.30.00 RA.xlsm'Removed Feature: Object from /xl/workbook.xml part (Workbook)

I went through the code to make sure "with thisworkbook" is used to avoid confrontation with other workbooks and this does not help. Re-installed Excel and reset windows. Resetting Windows helped for a bit then the problem surfaced again.

Comment: Try asking at [Sharepoint SE](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/) I do not have access to Sharepoint to test your code.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The AutoSave feature in Excel was messing with my VBA. I have used "ActiveWorkbook.AutoSaveOn = False" in the Open Workbook event to resolve this.